# F#: How do I pattern match a type value?

Tags: generics, f#, types, pattern-matching

I have a function that takes a generic parameter, and inside it I need to execute one of two functions depending on the type of the parameter.

```
member this.Load<'T> _path =
    let hhType = typeof<HooHah>
    match typeof<'T> with
        | hhType -> this.LoadLikeCrazy<'T> _path
        | _ -> this.LoadWithPizzaz<'T> _path
```

.... where LoadLikeCrazy and LoadWithPizzaz both return a 'T.

VS informs me that the wildcard case will never get executed, since I am apparently getting the type of a generic at compile time, and not the actual type at runtime.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your code , the first pattern match rule doesn't compare  typeof<'T>  against hhType. Instead, it will introduce a new value called hhType. That's the reason you got warning. 
I'd rather modify the code like this.

```
member this.Load<'T> _path =        
    match typeof<'T> with        
    | x when x = typeof<HooHah>  -> this.LoadLikeCrazy<'T> _path        
    | _ -> this.LoadWithPizzaz<'T> _path
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `_path` an instance of `'T`? If so, Talljoe's solution will work, otherwise you'll have to do something like:

```
member this.Load<'T> _path =
    if typeof<'T> = typeof<HooHah> then this.LoadLikeCrazy<'T> _path
    else this.LoadWithPizzaz<'T> _path
```

The reason for the error is that `hhType` within your `match` expression is shadowing the prior declaration of `hhType`. So, it's merely capturing the value of your match expression into a new binding. This matches everything, therefore your wildcard condition will never be hit.

Answer (score 0):

What nyinyithann has mentioned is correct. I wrote the below code in F#

```
let Hello name = 
let n = "Sample"
match name with
| n -> 1
| _ -> 0
```

Got the same warning. Used reflector to see what code is generate and found the below code (decompiled in C#)

```
public static int Hello<a>(a name)
{
  a local = name;
  a name = local;
  return 1;
}
```

Not sure why compiler did this :( . Can anyone describe this behaviour ?

Comment: What behavior do you expect from your code? You pattern match over name i.e. (match name with) then you provide two alternatives, in the first rule you create a new variable binding, also called "name", and then return 0. Since you don't specify any pattern or when guard the first rule will always be matched, meaning the second rule is redundant. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have updated the code.. actually the first pattern was : n -> 1 ... after giving it a though it seems that the "names" (variables) - in this case "n" -  defined inside match have their own scope and has nothing to do with bindings done before match block

Comment: You can get the behavior you’re looking for using the Literal attribute, Chris Smith has more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/10/03/f-zen-the-literal-attribute.aspx

Comment: @Robert - I don't think that will work. `typeof<...>` is not considered a constant expression.